# Entity does not inherit mappedsuperclass mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My symfony project use multiple bundles which handle different parts of the application.

Those bundle have MappedSuperclass and interfaces (to link them with resolve_target_entity in a CompilerPass).
My project has entities which extends those MappedSuperclass.

When using different entity managers with distinct connections, I can't figure out how to use the mapping from the MappedSuperclass. I have an error **"No identifier/primary key specified for Entity App\Entity\xx sub class of Bundle Bundle\Entity\xx. Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key."**

**App Entity** :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Bundle\User\Entity\User as CoreUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User extends CoreUser
{
}
```

**Bundle MappedSupperClass** :

```
namespace Bundle\User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]

class User implements UserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 128)]
    private string $someThing;
}
```

**Doctrine.yaml** :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL)%'
            user:
                url: '%env(resolve:USER_DATABASE_URL)%'
        default_connection: default
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            user:
                connection: user
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    UserBundle:
                        is_bundle: true
                        dir: 'src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'Bundle\User\Entity'
                        type: attribute
            default:
                connection: default
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        type: attribute
```

I'm still new to symfony and doctrine, I'm probably missing something. Will appreciate any help I can get to undestand this. Thanks!

Comment: The error message (and documentation on MappedSuperClasses) is pretty clear. All Entities require an $id property. Add it to your Entity and your problem is solved. [Documentation and proper example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) found using the first hit on Google: "Mapped superclasses ... are not query-able, and need not have an #[Id] property."

Comment: Hello Såpe, even if I add the Id property, it will not inherits from the other properties (in this example, someThing). The user table is created with only one field "id" and "someThing" is still missing. The MappedSuperClass mapping is ignored. MappedSuperClass are not query-able but should'nt the Id field be passed to the entity ? It seems to work fine when I'm using the same entity manager with only one connection. Thanks for your help.